# Is it possible to do this loop in a one-liner?

Tags: python, loops

Does anybody know how to do this in a one-liner?

```py
def epad(data):
    data = data.upper()
    out = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        out.append(ord(data[i]))
    return out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def epad(data):
    return [ord(ch) for ch in data.upper()]
```

or you can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
def epad(data):
    return list(map(ord, data.upper()))
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Microsoft This is not one-liner as you mentioned. You might want to take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`lambda`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp) and [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension):

```
epad = lambda data: [ord(c) for c in data.upper()]
```

### Edit:

If you prefer using `def` and not `lambda` then I also got it covered in one liner:

```
def epad(data): return [ord(c) for c in data.upper()]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I actually only meant the loop part, I'd prefer to use `def` for many reasons. But I can say that lambda didn't even occur to me.

Comment: @Microsoft As you wish. But I would prefer using `lambda`. It made the whole lot simpler

Comment: @Microsoft Check the edit. It uses `def` and all in single line.